# How to implement single sign on in joomla?

Tags: database, joomla, single-sign-on, centralized

Here is the scenario:

I want to implement single sign on in joomla.

User's data should be at central database(Main site).

And there will be multiple sites(may have their own database).
They might be hosted on separate domain or a sub domain of main site.

I have searched on Google and came across some extensions like JMultisite and JFusion.

But could not find how they actually work at back end.

**My requirements:**

1. User's database should be at main site
2. Single Sign On should be possible
3. Sites should be independent(development and deployment point of view)
4. Intersite communication should be easy.

How should I implement this in joomla?

Any possible links or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `But could not find how they actually work at back end` >> Read the documentation provided by the developers of the extensions.

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for pointing it out. I will check the documentation. Still I would like to ask you, can you provide some suggestion to implement this scenario?

Comment: I would recommend JFusion. It has been the on Joomla extensions directory for nearly 6 years and is very popular.

Comment: You could use remote tables in mysql (users and sessions) for the "child" joomlas.  There are security issues to consider though, as hacking one site will take them all down.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn then why to go for this? Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Yes, the extensions mentioned by Lodder! When doing sso you should always be concerned with possible security flaws as they will affect more than one site.

Comment: Joomla already has an LDAP authentication plugin for this purpose. Check it out in the plugin manager. http://docs.joomla.org/LDAP